# Find the taylor expansion to $(x^2 + x)e^{2x}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

My task is this:

Find the taylor expansion to$$f(x)=(x^2 + x)e^{2x}.$$

My work so far:

We should get $$e^{x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}\implies e^{2x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(2x)^n}{n!}\implies (x^2+x)e^{2x}=(x^2+x)\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(2x)^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty2^n\frac{x^{n+2}+x^{n+1}}{n!}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty2^{n-1}\frac{x^{n+1}+x^n}{(n-1)!}.$$

After changing the index. Although I think this is a possible answer, I'm supposed to derive this formula:$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n+1}{(n-1)!}2^{n-2}x^n.$$

By the look of it, it looks like they've multiplied the series with $\frac{(n+1)}{2}$, but I'm not sure why. I need this for my next exercise, and would like someone to point out any error or explain the missing step this formula. Thanks in advace!

Comment: Hint: Split the sum into $\sum Ax^{n+1} + \sum Bx^n$. Note the final answer does not involve $x^{n+1}$.

Comment: @kennytm Splitting up I'm getting: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{n-1}\frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{n-1}\frac{x^n}{(n-1)!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^n\frac{x^n}{n!}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{n-1}\frac{x^n}{(n-1)!}=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^n\frac{x^n}{n!}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{n-1}\frac{x^n}{(n-1)!}=1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( \frac{2^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}+\frac{2^n}{n!}\right)x^n=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{n2^{n-1}+2^n}{n!}\right)x^n=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{n+2}{n!}\right)2^{n-1}x^n.$ Close, but no cigar. What did i do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to work out the coefficient of a single power of $x$: let's call it $x^m$ to avoid confusion. In your case, the coefficient of $x^m$ is

${2^{m-2}}\frac{1}{(m-2)!}$ from your $x^{n+1}$ term

and

${2^{m-1}}\frac{1}{(m-1)!}$ from your $x^n$ term.

The first contribution can be rewritten as

${2^{m-2}}\frac{m-1}{(m-1)!}$

and the second can be rewritten as

${2^{m-2}}\frac{2}{(m-1)!}$.

Putting the two together, remembering that $(m-1)+2=(m+1)$, and replacing the $m$s with $n$s will get you your result.